# Selecting n real numbers between 0 and 1 at random, what is the probability they are in order, increasing?

Tags: probability, real-numbers

If I select n **distinct** real numbers $[0-1]$ at random, there are $n!$ arrangements of those numbers. Only one of the arrangements is in order from least to greatest. Hence:

P(n distinct reals increasing order)=$\frac{1}{n!}$ likewise

P(n distinct reals increasing or decreasing order)=$\frac{2}{n!}$

Is this still true if the numbers are **not** required to be distinct? I suspect yes, but why?

I want to say that getting the same real numbers more than once has probability of effectively 0, but this feels like hand waving and also potentially incorrect.

Comment: Acually no, because if a<b, then a must come before b. But if a=b, they can change position.

Comment: Your last argument is not hand waving, and it is very much correct. Regardless of whether having duplicates qualifies as "in order", we get $$P(\text{all in order}) = P(\text{all distinct})\cdot P(\text{all distinct numbers in order}) + P(\text{there are duplicates})\cdot P(\text{the numbers are still in order})$$The second terms disappears because of the $0$, and the first term immideately simplifies into $P(\text{all distinct numbers in order})$, which is equal to $\frac1{n!}$ or $\frac2{n!}$, depending as above on what "in order" means.

Comment: Even though it's theoretically possible to get duplicates, it's such a rare occurrance that whether or not you allow them to happen doesn't affect the calculations at all.

Comment: Arthur you should make that comment an answer since it answers my question perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In order to talk about probabilities in this situation, you need to have a measure; the obvious one here is Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]^n$.

For that measure, the subset of $[0,1]^n$ having any two numbers equal has measure 0. (This is not hard to prove with even a modicum of measure theory.) So your intuition is correct, and your "hand-waving" argument is easily turned into a formal proof with the right tools.

Historical note: before Kolmogorov worked out the connections between probability and measure theory, lots of questions like this caused a lot of puzzlement and sometimes even lead to paradoxes.